# Hibernate - Extract parameter values from SQL query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, parameters

I have a class that populates a Hibernate SQL query's parameters with different values depending on some input criteria. I would like to write tests for the resulting query. As of yet, I have not found a way to get the parameter values that were set on a query. I looked at the resulting Query implementation (in this case, SQLQueryImpl) and there is a method called getParameterMetadata() that seems like it might give me something, but I haven't been able to find anything.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
assertEquals("some value", query.getParameterValue(parameterName));
```

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

I just looked a little more, and I found a

```
query.getQueryParameters(map).getNamedParameters()
```

which returns a Map. I have to assume that the map contains the parameters and their values. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't consider the fact that because I'm testing, I can simply mock the query and expect specific parameters.